# Identify DOM events in HTML response

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I am sending multiple HTTP requests to server and getting a HTML + JS response. I want to check which all responses are producing JS alert or any DOM based events. To send HTTP requests I am using Node.js

Specially when there is a local JS at client and if user enters alert(123) it will produce a JS alert. So parsing original response will not help as data is not coming from server, it is limited to client only.

Ho do I enter data and re-render the HTML?

How do I automate this? Need suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have a very hard time doing this without a real browser.

I'd use the headless browser [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to render the page and run javascript. It even has an [`onAlert`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-alert.html) handler!